# How to debug iOS application using Xcode with Browserstack?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, browserstack

I want to debug my application using Browserstack, Is it possible ? I can test whole application by uploading IPA, but I want to debug line by line like we do with simulator or using real device. I didn't find any document that help me to find a way to debug application using xcode and Browserstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserStack cannot be used for line by line debugging as there is no feature to connect Xcode with BrowserStack.

It can be used for functionally testing your iOS apps.